# How to import an external library into an Ansible module?

Tags: python, ansible

I would like to add Ansible module locally. The module should use external Python library. I have added just the following line:

```
from ansible.module_utils.foo import Bar
```

to the Ansible new module template making it look like below:

**my_test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Copyright: (c) 2018, Terry Jones <terry.jones@example.org>
# GNU General Public License v3.0+ (see COPYING or https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.txt)

ANSIBLE_METADATA = {
    'metadata_version': '1.1',
    'status': ['preview'],
    'supported_by': 'community'
}

DOCUMENTATION = '''
---
module: my_test

short_description: This is my test module

version_added: "2.4"

description:
    - "This is my longer description explaining my test module"

options:
    name:
        description:
            - This is the message to send to the test module
        required: true
    new:
        description:
            - Control to demo if the result of this module is changed or not
        required: false

extends_documentation_fragment:
    - azure

author:
    - Your Name (@yourhandle)
'''

EXAMPLES = '''
# Pass in a message
- name: Test with a message
  my_test:
    name: hello world

# pass in a message and have changed true
- name: Test with a message and changed output
  my_test:
    name: hello world
    new: true

# fail the module
- name: Test failure of the module
  my_test:
    name: fail me
'''

RETURN = '''
original_message:
    description: The original name param that was passed in
    type: str
    returned: always
message:
    description: The output message that the test module generates
    type: str
    returned: always
'''

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from ansible.module_utils.foo import Bar


def run_module():
    # define available arguments/parameters a user can pass to the module
    module_args = dict(
        name=dict(type='str', required=True),
        new=dict(type='bool', required=False, default=False)
    )

    # seed the result dict in the object
    # we primarily care about changed and state
    # change is if this module effectively modified the target
    # state will include any data that you want your module to pass back
    # for consumption, for example, in a subsequent task
    result = dict(
        changed=False,
        original_message='',
        message=''
    )

    # the AnsibleModule object will be our abstraction working with Ansible
    # this includes instantiation, a couple of common attr would be the
    # args/params passed to the execution, as well as if the module
    # supports check mode
    module = AnsibleModule(
        argument_spec=module_args,
        supports_check_mode=True
    )

    # if the user is working with this module in only check mode we do not
    # want to make any changes to the environment, just return the current
    # state with no modifications
    if module.check_mode:
        module.exit_json(**result)

    # manipulate or modify the state as needed (this is going to be the
    # part where your module will do what it needs to do)
    result['original_message'] = module.params['name']
    result['message'] = 'goodbye'

    # use whatever logic you need to determine whether or not this module
    # made any modifications to your target
    if module.params['new']:
        result['changed'] = True

    # during the execution of the module, if there is an exception or a
    # conditional state that effectively causes a failure, run
    # AnsibleModule.fail_json() to pass in the message and the result
    if module.params['name'] == 'fail me':
        module.fail_json(msg='You requested this to fail', **result)

    # in the event of a successful module execution, you will want to
    # simple AnsibleModule.exit_json(), passing the key/value results
    module.exit_json(**result)

def main():
    run_module()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't introduced any changes in Ansible playbook template. I paste playbook here for neatness:

**testmod.yml**

```
- name: test my new module
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: run the new module
    my_test:
      name: 'hello'
      new: true
    register: testout
  - name: dump test output
    debug:
      msg: '{{ testout }}'
```

I have put module **my_test.py** in the following localization:

```
~/.ansible/plugins/modules
```

I have extended **ANSIBLE_MODULE_UTILS** environment variable making **foo** library visible. Generally, leaving aside Ansible, parts of **foo** library may be imported to the Python script in the following way:

```
from foo import Bar
```

I have tested, that when e.g. **foo** is a Python script and **Bar** is a class inside that script, the **testmod.yml** playbook may be run correctly. The problem is that **foo** is a directory, there is not **foo.py** file, nor **Bar.py**. In my case, when I run **testmod.yml**, I receive traceback:

```
ImportError: No module named foo.config
```

Could you tell me what should I do to be able to use **foo** external library in my local Ansible module?

Comment: I didnt dig deep in your code. but if i may ask, did you check that your module exist in PATH or in sys.path ?

Comment: You can iterate over sys.path and check if the directory or package paht in python words exist in the list. if not you can insert its path by sys.path.insert()

Comment: @Adam I didn't. After extending **sys.path** it started to work correctly. I was misleaded by the fact, that Ansible was able to find **foo** when it was a Python script inserted in that path without extending **sys.path**